# webビューアプリにおける「フェイスブックにシェア」の実装

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook

初めてアプリ作成に取り組んでいます。

webビューを用いたandroidアプリから「フェイスブックにシェア」を実装しようとしています。 
＊自作ボタンにてです。公式ボタンは使いたくない事情の為です。。

投稿画面までは表示され、実際に「シェア」ができる（できた）ことは確認できたのですが、 
投稿画面で「キャンセル」「投稿する」を押すと真っ白画面になってしまい、シェア完了画面？に移れません。

＊端末の戻るボタンを押すと、再度フェイスブック側の「シェア」画面に戻ります。（既にシェア完了しているのに） 
＊あとは強制終了しかない状態で、自分のアプリに戻ってくれません。。

該当箇所のソースを登載しますので、どなたかお詳しい方いらっしゃいましたらどこが悪いか、アドバイス等いただけますと幸いです。

ビルドはAndroidStudioで行いました。

※前提※

1. facebookアカウントにてアプリにログインしている状態
2. facebookのjavascriptSDKは読み込んでる状態
3. jqueryは動作しており、FB.ui();まで処理は到達している
4. 実際にシェアができたことは確認済み

ソースコード

```js
<p><button class="midium blue" id="post_facebook">facebookに公開する</button></p> 

// Facebook投稿ボタン押下 
$('#post_facebook').on('click', function(){ 
    FB.ui({ 
        method: 'share', 
        href: 指定リンク先URL 
    }, function(response) { 
        //ここの処理に来ていない様子。。 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

どのタイミングでClickをバインドしてるか分かりませんし、
全容が見えないのでFBが何処で宣言されているのかも分かりません。
WebViewアプリと言うのが、`Cordova`のようなフレームワークなのか
それともサーバ、またはアプリに内包されているWebページを`WebView`で見せているだけなのか
不明点が多いので気になる点だけ記載します。

- jQueryは正しく初期化されているか？
  　　ｊQueryを使っているようですが正しく初期化されていますか？
  　　クリックをバインドする箇所でｊQueryが動作しない……なんてことはありませんか？
- クリックイベントの関数には到達していますか？
  　　関数が発動していなければそもそも実行されません。
  　　バインドが上手くいっているか改めて確認してください。
- `FB`は宣言されており、内包されているオブジェクト内には関数`ui`は存在しますか？
  　　`FB`が初期化される前に呼び出しても中身が無ければ動作しません。
  　　クリック時に`FB`が正しく初期化出来ているか確認してください。
- コールバックには到達していないみたいですが、シェア自体は出来ましたか？
  　　シェア自体が出来ていなければ、そもそも`FB`が正しい動きをしているかが分かりません
  　　また、シェアが出来ていても中身がおかしければパラメータが渡っていない事になりますので仕様の確認が必要です。
  　　他、コールバックに到達した確認はどうやってされたのでしょうか？

以上、参考になれば……と思います。

---

**追記**　　
補足の中で分からないのが"画面が真っ白になる"という点です。
本来新しくウィンドウやタブを開き投稿するはずの物が
`window.open`で上書きされていると思います。
自身のウィンドウを上書きして遷移しているためです。

また、WebSDKを使用しているようですが、
アプリ側の方はどうなっているのでしょうか？
未だ実装方法が不明瞭です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。いただいた視点でチェックを行いました。
・クリックをバインドする箇所でｊQueryが動作しない……なんてことはありませんか？
・クリックイベントの関数には到達していますか？
　→FB.ui();の直前にalert ("kiteiru");を入れて表示を確認しました。
・FBは宣言されており、内包されているオブジェクト内には関数uiは存在しますか？シェア自体は出来ましたか？
　→https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui/　こちらの関数が動いており、実際にシェア自体は出来ました。
・コールバックに到達した確認はどうやってされたのでしょうか？
　→function(response) { 
        //ここの処理が動くはずなのですが、真っ白画面になって確認できていません（到達していないと思われます）
    });

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。他の回答者の方にも見やすいよう補足事項等は質問内容に追記する形でお願いいたします。